# K-Nearest Neighbour Implementation in Java

Tags: java, knn

I'm looking for a decent implementation of KNN algorithm in java because, in my dissertation, I have to modify it using different data structures.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://gitlab.com/koraytugay/programming-challenges-java/tree/master/src/biz/tugay/iris_flower_knn

Answer (score 5):

[Here is](http://blog.afewguyscoding.com/2010/05/nearest-neighbors-java/) full implementation and description.

Comment: This implementation is not optimized. A good implementation would use structures like a KD-Tree to find the K-Nearest-Neighboor efficiently.

Comment: The link is dead :/